# RTCFileLogger: How to decode log file?

Tags: android, ios, webrtc, webrtc-android, webrtc-ios

If you use `RTCFileLogger` or `RTCPeerConnection`'s `startRtcEventLogWithFilePath` they both log data that seems to be encoded in some format that is not human readable:

```
    ∆äÚïï
‡“ÚïïZÃÆë∫
"øÃ˛ïï¢≤›”± (08@H
˝Ã˛ïï™≤›”±
›Õ˛ïï™≤›”±
"†Œ˛ïï¢≤›”± (08@H
"Åœ˛ïï¢≤›”± (08@H
ÇÃÅñï™≤›”±
¸ÃÅñï™≤›”±
ú Ññï™≤›”±
ÑÀÑñï™≤›”±
"ÉÀáñï¢˛Ãá¡ (08@H
∫Àáñï™˛Ãá¡
"«øçñï¢°ûƒ» (08@H
¸øçñï™°ûƒ»
∏¿çñï™°ûƒ»
"˙∑êñï¢ıÿØ† (08@H
¶∏êñï™ıÿØ†
Â∏êñï™ıÿØ†
"⁄±ìñï¢‚ÜÓÜ (08@H
î≤ìñï™‚ÜÓÜ
```

How do you decode this data?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using `RTCCallbackLogger` instead of `RTCFileLogger` and logging the logs to file using another framework